# How to calculate the percentage when reading the file?

Tags: c++, c

I want to know how can I calculate the percentage while I am reading data from a file stream. I tried this way and all I am getting is zero

```
typedef struct Counter{
    int range1,range2,range3,range4;
    double preset1 ,preset2 ,preset3 ,preset4;
}  countType;

    void analysis_range(double d, countType &ctp) {

        // from 0 to 1.00 KM
        if (d >= 0.00 && d <= 1.00) {
            ctp.range1 += 1;
            ctp.preset1 = ((ctp.range1 / (ctp.range1 + ctp.range2 + ctp.range3 +
                                          ctp.range4)));
        }
        // from 1.00 to 2.00 KM
        else if (d > 1.00 && d <= 2.00) {
            ctp.range2 += 1;
            ctp.preset2 = ((ctp.range2 / (ctp.range1 + ctp.range2 + ctp.range3 +
                                          ctp.range4))) *
                          10;
        }
        // from 1.00 to 2.00 KM
        else if (d > 2.00 && d <= 5.00) {
            ctp.range3 += 1;
            ctp.preset3 = ((ctp.range3 / (ctp.range1 + ctp.range2 + ctp.range3 +
                                          ctp.range4))) *
                          10;
        }
        // grater than 5.00 KM
        else if (d > 5.00) {
            ctp.range4 += 1;
            ctp.preset4 = ((ctp.range4 / (ctp.range1 + ctp.range2 + ctp.range3 +
                                          ctp.range4))) *
                          10;
        }
    }

    void ProcesData(int rank, int numProcs) {

        static countType count;
        MPI_Datatype recType = createRecType();
        // read file and populate the vectors
        ifstream foodbankFile("foodbanks.dat");
        ifstream residenceFile("residences.dat");

        // populate datavector
        std::vector<Foodbank> foodbankData(
            (std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>(foodbankFile)),
            std::istream_iterator<Foodbank>());

        Residence res;
        int numLines = 0;

        while (!residenceFile.eof()) {
            residenceFile >> res.x >> res.y;

            if (numLines % numProcs == rank) {
                // call the  process
                // populate_distancesVector(res,foodbankData);
                analysis_range(populate_distancesVector(res, foodbankData),
                               count);
            }
            ++numLines;
        }

        std::cout << "for Rank" << rank << ",from 0 to 1.00 KM:" << count.range1
                  << ",%" << count.preset1
                  << ",from 1.00 to 2.00 KM:" << count.range2 << ",%"
                  << count.preset2 << ",from 2.00 to 5.00 KM:" << count.range3
                  << ",%" << count.preset3
                  << ",grater than 5.00 KM:" << count.range4 << ",%"
                  << count.preset3 << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm pretty sure you'll have to ask the question in english. It's impossible to understand now.

Comment: The percentage of what, please?

Comment: @PawełStawarz; Hufff.. I tried my best. :) Hope it will make sense now.

Comment: srroy forget to add my struct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably getting zero because ctp.range1 to ctp.range4 are not floating point values. If you divide an integer by an integer, the result becomes an integer as well. Cast one of the operands to float or double, like this:

```
ctp.preset1 = (((float) ctp.range1/(ctp.range1+ctp.range2+ctp.range3+ctp.range4)));
```

Comment: How you come to know `ctp.range1` is not `float`? o__O

Comment: Guessed it because you said you were getting zero no matter what you try. Wrong?

Comment: Haccks, You haven't given us the types for range or preset, but range=int and preset=double would be the most common, and would frequently lead to the trouble you describe.

Comment: @Richard I don't think Haccks is the one who asked the question?

Comment: @RichardPlunkett; You also understood wrong. I am not the one that asked the question :D. By the way +1 for both of you.

Answer (score 1):

So, I understand that ctp.preset1 is suppose to hold the percentage for range 1, based onthe count in ctp.range1.

The reason you aregetting zero, if that you are using integers, in this part of the equation:

```
(ctp.range1/(ctp.range1+ctp.range2+ctp.range3+ctp.range4))
```

This will always evaluate to zero for meaningful range counts, as integer maths truncates. Change it to:

```
(ctp.range1/double(ctp.range1+ctp.range2+ctp.range3+ctp.range4))
```

and all should be fine.